# Hooking TNotifyEvent / looking for a proper way to use method and procedural pointers

Tags: delphi, pointers, methods, event-hooking

I'm looking for easy way to create TNotifyEvent hook/wrapper
So I got an idea to create it as object to make stuff easier

**But I have no idea how to attach / swap method pointers correctly... :/**

Maybe anyone of You has done similar things before?

Here is the skeleton of my class

```
  TNotifyEventHook = class
  private
    NotifyEvent: ???????;
    OldProc, NewProc: ???????;

    FContinueEventChain: Boolean;
    procedure Wrapper(Sender: TObject);
  public
    constructor Create(OriginalNotifyEvent: ???????; ChainNotifyEvent???????);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property ContinueEventChain: Boolean read FContinueEventChain write FContinueEventChain default True;
  end;



constructor TNotifyEventHook.Create(OriginalNotifyEvent: ???????; ChainNotifyEvent: ???????);
begin
  NotifyEvent := ???????   // save
  OldProc := ???????
  NewProc := ???????

  NotifyEvent := ??????? // redirect NotifyEvent to Wrapper
end;

destructor TNotifyEventHook.Destroy;
begin                                 
  ???????   // detach chain
end;

procedure TNotifyEventHook.Wrapper(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(NewProc) then
    NewProc(Sender);
  if FContinueEvenChain and Assigned(OldProc) then
    OldProc(Sender);
end;
```

**I'd be really grateful for help... Or maybe just better ideas?**

Comment: I dont realy Understanc what you are trying to do? Do you want to add an extra event to sat Button.OnClick?

Comment: *".. how to attach .."* - Attach to where? You're passing a method to the constructor that is attached to a property of some object. That method does not know which object, if there is one, it is attached to, and to which event handler.

Answer (score 0):

This is not gonna work because you cannot *store* the reference to an event property itself in a variable or parameter. The NotifyEvent *ís* the OldProc/NewProc. In other words: the thing that is stored in an event property is the event handler which get called when the property is fired from within the objects internals. So a valid `TNotifyEvent` instance only tells which routine gets called, not to which object nor property the routine is linked to.

If your question would be limited to one specific event, e.g. `TControl.OnClick`, then the following works. Otherwise, I suggest you use a multi-cast event model, for example like `TApplicationEvents` does.

```
type
  TOnClickRedirector = class
  private
    FControl: TControl;
    FFireOriginalToo: Boolean;
    FOriginal: TNotifyEvent;
    FRedirect: TNotifyEvent;
    procedure Fire(Sender: TObject);
  public
    constructor Create(Control: TControl; OnClick: TNotifyEvent);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property FireOriginalToo: Boolean read FFireOriginalToo
      write FFireOriginalToo default True;
  end;

  TControlAccess = class(TControl);

{ TOnClickRedirector }

constructor TOnClickRedirector.Create(Control: TControl; OnClick: TNotifyEvent);
begin
  FControl := Control;
  FOriginal := TControlAccess(FControl).OnClick;
  FRedirect := OnClick;
  TControlAccess(FControl).OnClick := Fire;
  FFireOriginalToo := True;
end;

destructor TOnClickRedirector.Destroy;
begin
  TControlAccess(FControl).OnClick := FOriginal;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TOnClickRedirector.Fire(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(FRedirect) then
    FRedirect(Sender);
  if FFireOriginalToo and Assigned(FOriginal) then
    FOriginal(Sender);
end;
```

Copy this for each specific event you would like to intercept. Beware that this code example does not safeguard the possibility that `FControl` does not exist anymore at this object's destruction. Therefore it would be best to descend from `TComponent` and use `FreeNotification`.

Comment: Regarding multicasting, have a look at Allen Bauer's blog for his implementation: [Multicast events using generics](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2008/08/15/38865)

Comment: Blog post has moved to [Multicast events using generics](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/multicast-events-using-generics/)